# am I allowed to use "D'you" in everyday American conversation?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

This [site](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dyou) says:

**D'you is a shortened form of 'do you' or 'did you', used in spoken English.**
*⇒ What d'you say?*

It would seem that more British people say like that. Not sure about American.

Am I allowed to use "**D'you**" in everyday American conversation?

Is this kind of saying popular in America?

Comment: Where does the dictionary imply it's  British English? Everyone, regardless of their education, pronounces *do you* that way, how they spell it is different matter. Collins Dictionary is saying that particular spelling is used.  One other thing, "Do you"  and "D'you" are not *sayings* or *proverbs*.

Comment: D'you is NOT a shortened form of DID you. First, it's one way to imitate what one hears. A shortened form is: didn't for did not. And D'you is not that. When people speak fast in AmE, one often does /D'you/. It would be found  written like that in novels, plays, scenarios. FYI, the past is Didya.

Comment: In fact, British speakers also say: D'you. Typically AmE is: Doya for do you.

Answer (score 1):

You can speak that way, and you will be understood by native or experienced English speakers. You wouldn't write it though. Even if you wrote down what a person said, you wouldn't write "d'you" instead of "do you".

Comment: Never say never (joke). There is such a thing as written dialogue. So, it could be written in novels, plays and movie scripts.

Answer (score 0):

In you feel comfortable with using it you can, in the same conversations that you use "gonna", "gotta" and "wanna".

But it makes sense only if you speak fast enough to "need" to mosh your syllables together.

Comment: There is nothing that irks me more than hearing a French person speak English who uses wanna and gonna in somewhat non-colloquial sentences. Many English speakers when speaking fast say D'you in perfectly formed sentences and not necessarily with wanna or gonna.

Comment: @Lambie You're right, and I only use those when the conversation is casual enough, if I have even a slight doubt I absolutely avoid them. But I'll also avoid "D'you" in that case (maybe that's just me, I don't feel comfortable enough with it yet). I'm saying if you are in a conversation *so casual* that you can use "gonna", you can also use "D''you", but the opposite is not necessarily true.

Comment: Ok, I agree with that.